# checkbox hides problem when we click on it

Tags: javascript

I have added an click event to the class `sec` which will show and hide the checkbox.
But when I click on checkbox, then checkbox hides.

```js
let sec = document.querySelector('.sec');
let checkbox = document.querySelector('.switch');

sec.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  checkbox.classList.toggle("show");
})
```

```css
.sec{
  background:lightgray;
  padding:10px;
  width:450px;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:70px;
}

.switch{
  display:none;
  background:gray;
  padding:5px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom : 100%
}
.switch::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    background: #88b7d5;
    background: #242334;
    border: 1px solid #3F3E5B; 
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec">
  <p>Click me to show popup</p>
  <div class="popup">
    <label class="switch">
      I am checkbox
      <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Since the checkbox is inside the DIV, clicking on the checkbox also sends a click event to the DIV because of event bubbling.

Comment: then how to stop this behaviour. I don't want to add click event to any other element.

Comment: Add an event listener to the checkbox that calls `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: added `document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    event.stopPropagation()  
})
` but not working. same problem.

Comment: It works for me, see my answer below. Is the checkbox the only input on the page?

Comment: I am editing this code in codepen. there is not working.

Comment: What's the codepen link?

Answer (score 0):

The click on the checkbox is also a click on the section because the checkbox is inside the section, so the event listener is toggling the checkbox.

Add an event listener on the checkbox label that uses `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling to the container.

```js
let sec = document.querySelector('.sec');
let label = document.querySelector('.switch');

sec.addEventListener('click', () => {
  label.classList.toggle("show");
})

label.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
.sec {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.switch {
  display: none;
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%
}

.switch::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  background: #88b7d5;
  background: #242334;
  border: 1px solid #3F3E5B;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec">
  <p>Click me to show popup</p>
  <div class="popup">
    <label class="switch">
      I am checkbox
      <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: But now if i click on label then it hides.

Comment: Then put the event listener on the label.

Comment: Don't why but I just login to codepen then it starts working on codepen too. Earlier I was just using codepen without login.

Comment: Okay I got it. //////

Comment: You probably changed something else

Comment: May be. but its too fun for me.